# Displaying data from the database on Java JTree

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a database with two columns named
 colNode,colLeaf

When I read data from the database and display it on the JTree

```
while (resultSet.next()) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode url = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(resultSet.getString("colNode"));
            mutableTreeNode.add(url);
            url.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(resultSet.getString("colLeaf")));
        }
```

I would like if the value already exists on JTree colNode then colLeaf will be appended to the.I want to get the results in Figure 2
Please help me

Current output:

[image: Current output]

Desired output:

[image: Desired output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you mean, that you want to group all the `colLeaf` with the same `colNode`?

I'd start by doing one of two things, either use the SQL to group and/or sort your results by `colNode`, this way you could monitor the current "group" and when it changes, create a new `TreeNode`

Something like...

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode rootNode = ...;
DefaultMutableTreeNode groupNode = null;
String currentGroup = null;
while (resultSet.next()) {
    String group = resultSet.getString("colNode");
    if (currentGroup == null || !currentGroup.equals(group)) {
        currentGroup = group;
        group = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(group);
        rootNode.add(groupNode);
    }
    group.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(resultSet.getString("colLeaf")));
}
```

for example.

Or, use somekind of `Map`, to map all the `colNode` values under the same key (`colLeaf`)

```
Map<String, List<String>> mapGroups = new HashMap<>(25);
while (resultSet.next()) {
    String group = resultSet.getString("colNode");
    List<String> members = mapGroups.get(group);
    if (members == null) {
        members = new ArrayList<>(25);
        mapGroups.put(group, members);
    }
    members.add(resultSet.getString("colLeaf"));
}
```

You would then use the `mapGroups` to generate your `TreeNode`s based on the key/value groups.

for example.

Personally, I think the first option is more efficient, but might require a more complex query, the second option is slower and requires more overhead, but models the data in manner which is similar to that which you are trying to achieve

Comment: Yes, I would like if the value already exists on JTree colNode then colLeaf will be appended to the.

Please help me